# From Matlab to Python, diagonalisation of matrices

Tags: python, numpy

In matlab, it is possible to get all the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors 
of a sparse matrix sp _mat
by just calling:

```
[v_n, e_n] = eig(sp _mat)
```

and, if the matrix is very sparse, the diagonalisation can be much fast than

```
[v_n, e_n] = eig(full(sp _mat))
```

Do you know if a similar function, which speeds up the complete diagonalisation of a sparse matrix, exists in Python?
Many thanks!

Comment: There is support for sparse matrices in [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html#)

Comment: You might want to have a look at `scipy.sparse.linalg`. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.8.x/reference/sparse.linalg.html
Especially the `eigen` function might be interesting for you.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Many thanks!!!

Comment: Actually, I had a look to scipy.sparse.linalg, but it does't give access to the full spectrum. And I will need it.

Comment: Do your matrices have many completely zero columns/rows? If yes, each one corresponds to a zero eigenvalue and those can be projected out first (which needs some thinking how to do, but is possible), which reduces the size of the eigenproblem that in the end needs to be solved. I'm not sure what the Matlab routine does, but this is one way to get significant speedups. Alternatively (but this is not necessarily faster), you can use `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs` to compute `n-2` eigenvalues, and then solve the remaining 2x2 eigenvalue problem with `numpy.linalg.eig`.